# Using DOMDocument and DOMXPath how can I ignore some characters for the match?

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath

I'm using the [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to determine the presence of some phrase (Keyword phrase) in my HTML content, for example to search if the Keyword is in Bold. I use the follow code and works fine except that I need to "ignore" some characters when the keyword is searched. With the follow code:

```
$characters_to_ignore = array(':','(',')','/');
$keyword = 'keyword AAA';
$content = "Some HTML content for example <b>keyword: AAA</b> and other HTML";
$exp = '//b[contains(., "' . $keyword . '")]|//strong[contains(., "' . $keyword . '")]|//span[contains(@style, "bold") and contains(., "' .  $keyword . '")]';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(strtolower($content));
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query($exp);
```

I would need to identify "keyword: AAA" as well as "keyword AAA", so I need to specify to the DOMXPath query to ignore the characters in variable $characters_to_ignore when search for the keyword phrase.

The previous code works fine for "keyword AAA", how can I change it to match "keyword: AAA" too? (and with any of the characters in $characters_to_ignore)

New Information:
Maybe using [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp#string)?

> fn:contains(string1,string2)

but I can't get a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you probably already solved it somehow, but here's the solution...

It would be trivial using XPath 2.0 method `matches()`, but PHP `DOMXPath` class supports only XPath 1.0 yet.

But as of PHP 5.3, `DOMXPath` class have the [registerPHPFunctions()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registerphpfunctions.php) method which allow us to use PHP functions as XPath functions. :)

Making it work:

```
$keyword = 'AAA';
$regex = "|keyword[:()/]? $keyword|";
$content = "Some HTML content for example <b>keyword: AAA</b> and other HTML";
$exp = "//b[php:functionString('preg_match', '$regex', .)]|//strong[php:functionString('preg_match', '$regex', .)]|//span[contains(@style, 'bold') and php:functionString('preg_match', '$regex', .)]";

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xpath->registerNamespace('php', 'http://php.net/xpath');
$xpath->registerPHPFunctions();
$elements = $xpath->query($exp);
```